# Signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package but there are no duplicates in dependency:tree

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I have a web app running under Tomcat 9.0.80. When I run Tomcat, I see an exception in the log. The stack trace is below. The reason of that exception is I have two org.eclipse.emf.common jars with different versions in lib directory:

```
ls -l | grep org.eclipse.emf.common
-rw-r----- 1 tomcat tomcat   375780 Jul  3  2023 org.eclipse.emf.common-2.18.0.jar
-rw-r----- 1 tomcat tomcat   211682 Nov 30 14:57 org.eclipse.emf.common-2.6.0.jar
```

If I remove 2.6.0, tomcat and my webapp start with no exceptions. I wanted to exclude 2.6.0 from my pom.xml but I was not able to find where this dependency comes from:

```
$ mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose=true | grep org.eclipse.emf.common
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.emf:org.eclipse.emf.common:jar:2.18.0:compile
$
```

There is only one 2.18.0 version of the library. I tried to use dependencyManager passing 2.18.0 to it but I still have two versions in my ./lib. What else I can do to exclude unwanted jar?

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl$EScannableAdapterList"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCerts(ClassLoader.java:891)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:661)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:754)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2337)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:810)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1293)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1141)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2337)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:810)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1293)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1141)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.impl.MinimalEObjectImpl.eAdapters(MinimalEObjectImpl.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.impl.EClassImpl.getESuperAdapter(EClassImpl.java:2227)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.impl.EClassImpl.getESuperTypes(EClassImpl.java:1714)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.impl.EcorePackageImpl.initializePackageContents(EcorePackageImpl.java:2530)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.impl.EcorePackageImpl.init(EcorePackageImpl.java:486)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EcorePackage.<clinit>(EcorePackage.java:67)
```

Comment: You should remove one of them so you only have *one* of those JARs.

Comment: Yes, that was what I said. The question was why maven adds two versions and how to prevent it. And why I don't see two versions in dependency:tree.

Comment: You're not providing sufficient information to diagnose that. Post your pom.xml and the dependeny:tree output.